# FreeBSD static routing set gateway to link

Tags: networking, routing, freebsd

I am running FreeBSD 8.1 and configuring static routes. What is the [route](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=route&sektion=8) command to set the gateway to [link#1](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/network-routing.html) and not an IP address?

I tried `route add default link#1` but FreeBSD doesn't take it. With Cisco IOS it's possible to route to a next-hop gateway this way with [ip route](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/12_2/iproute/command/reference/1rfindp1.html#wp1054112).  For example, Cisco IOS will take `ip route 172.16.2.0 255.255.255.0 Serial 0/0`.  What is the equivalent UNIX command to do the same?

I statically configured netif `em0` to `172.16.1.102`  The state of my FreeBSD instance shows link#1 exactly once as follows.

```
Destination     Gateway
...
localhost      link#3    UH   ...    lo0
172.16.1.0     link#1    U    ...    em0

...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to stop, take 10 giant steps back from the machine, and read the FreeBSD handbook section on networking (specifically [the section on Gateways and Routes](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/network-routing.html)).

. . . go ahead, this answer will still be here when you're done. . . .

You read it? Good.
Now you understand that what you're asking to do makes no sense, right?

---

FreeBSD generally handles routes two ways:

1. **I am connected to this network directly, via a NIC (interface, link)**
   The system knows this because when you configure an interface you provide an IP address and a netmask. Any machines on the subnet specified by that combination are reachable over that link.
2. **I can reach this network via a gateway machine with a specific IP address**
   The system knows this because you configure a route to a specific destination (a single address, a subnet, or the "default" route for any destination not otherwise specified), and tell it which machine (address) will be the gateway that it should send traffic to in order to reach that destination.
   Implicit in this is that you must be able to reach this gateway (either via a link as in (1) above, or via another gateway.

You cannot configure a `link` as a gateway - doing so makes no sense as any network(s) reachable via a specific link will be automatically configured for you when you configure the interface.

You *can* do other things (like simply spew traffic onto a serial line), which are all [documented in the handbook](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/) if you're actually in one of the rare situations where you would need to, but you've given no indication that you're in such a situation.

Comment: while overall helpful. your second link may as well be a "link to RTFM". 
which page?

Comment: @T.Webster The. Whole. Thing. (No, I'm not being facetious.) You are expected as a professional to read all the relevant documentation. If you're administering FreeBSD systems the whole handbook is relevant, and you should be at least familiar with its entire breadth of contents so you know where to look...)

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can only add "interface" routes on cisco with point-to-point interfaces, not multiple access ones like FastEthernet.

So, to make a default route with ethernet on cisco you should use "next hop" address like this:

> ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 FastEthernet0/0 172.16.2.1

Same things with BSD box. But if you only like to add network route as "ip route 172.16.2.0 255.255.255.0 Serial 0/0" with FBSD, you can do something about:

> route add 172.16.2.0/24 -iface em0

Answer (score 0):

You know, I added a second interface and configured it with an internal IP address (192.168.1.1) and was expecting to see a route to 192.168.1.0/24 to show up on link#4 or whatever this interface ended up being, but it wasn't there.  Thus it brought me to this question.  In the end, I rebooted pfSense out of desperation and BAM, there it was and things started working the way I needed.  Maybe this will not answer your exact question, but it answered mine.

In my situation I did have to do one more thing though to get it working: enable Hybrid outbound NAT and setup an outbound rule so that when traffic came into my server (TrueNAS in this case, FreeBSD) it appeared to be coming from the pfSense firewall itself (192.168.1.1) and could easily route it back on the correct interface:

https://docs.netgate.com/pfsense/en/latest/troubleshooting/nat.html#target-system-has-no-gateway-or-cannot-use-pfsense-as-its-gateway